# Example of a string translated by the .NET language packs

Tags: .net, wpf, localization

The description for the .NET language packs (in my case [the .NET 4.5.1 language pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40751)) say that they "contain translated error messages and other UI text".

Could someone give me an example of such translated text that I could test in e.g. a simple WPF application?

Comment: All of the Exception.Message property values for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example using a simple console app. Copy paste the code and replace the cultures by 2 cultures that are installed on your computer. For me en-US and fr-FR, you will see the exception message translated.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
string msg1 = new FileNotFoundException().Message;
Console.WriteLine(msg1);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
string msg2 = new FileNotFoundException().Message;
Console.WriteLine(msg2);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I'm still tripping over the "other UI text". If it's only the error messages the language packs would not make any sense to me since it's so much better to use the English error messages for searching solutions in the net. But I can't find any explanation about what that "other UI text" might be and if it's relevant in any way.